# Are args[0], args[1] variables?

Tags: java, arrays, string, variables, args

I have code like:

```java
public class Hi
{
  public static void main(String args[])
  {
    ...
  }
}
```

If I type the following commend “java Hi String1 String2”, how many objects.

The correct answer:

Objects: 3: "String1" object, "String2" object, the array point by args.

Variables:4: args, "String1", "String2", the array point by args.

And my question is:

If I can deem "String1" and "String2" in variable count as args[0] and args[1]? (That means args[0] and args[1] are variables.)

If the code is

```java
int a[2]={0};
```

I know that there are 1 array object and 2 variables (a, array object), but since String in Java is special, I'm wondering if I must take "String1" and "String2", or I can to take args[0] and args[1] as variables as follows?

Objects: 3: "String1" object, "String2" object, the array point by args.

Variables:4: args, args[0], args[1], the array point by args.

Comment: There us only one variable, and only if you count a parameter as a variable.

Comment: `args` is a single Object. Simply referencing the indexes doesn't create new variables until you assign them to something else

Comment: @SLaks: Yes, I count object as a class type variable.

Comment: `args` is just an array, nothing fancy. Read about arrays, then you know what it is and how to use it.

Comment: That's not what variable means.

Comment: @SLaks A parameter *is* a variable, see JLS [4.12.3. Kinds of Variables](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.12.3): **#4 Method parameters**: *"For every parameter declared in a method declaration, a new **parameter variable** is created each time that method is invoked"*

Answer (score -1):

**TL;DR** *Short answer:* Yes, `args[0]` and `args[1]` are variables.

---

According to JLS [4.12.3. Kinds of Variables](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.12.3), there are 8 kinds of variables. Of those, your code uses 3 of them:

> 2. An *instance variable* is a field declared within a class declaration without using the keyword `static` ([§8.3.1.1](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.3.1.1)).
>
>    If a class T has a field a that is an instance variable, then a new instance variable a is created and initialized to a default value ([§4.12.5](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.12.5)) as part of each newly created object of class T or of any class that is a subclass of T ([§8.1.4](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.1.4)). The instance variable effectively ceases to exist when the object of which it is a field is no longer referenced, after any necessary finalization of the object ([§12.6](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-12.html#jls-12.6)) has been completed.
> 3. *Array components* are unnamed variables that are created and initialized to default values ([§4.12.5](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.12.5)) whenever a new object that is an array is created ([§10 (Arrays)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-10.html), [§15.10.2](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.10.2)). The array components effectively cease to exist when the array is no longer referenced.
> 4. *Method parameters* ([§8.4.1](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.4.1)) name argument values passed to a method.
>
>    For every parameter declared in a method declaration, a new parameter variable is created each time that method is invoked ([§15.12](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.12)). The new variable is initialized with the corresponding argument value from the method invocation. The method parameter effectively ceases to exist when the execution of the body of the method is complete.

---

When you run `java Hi String1 String2`, you get:

- 3 objects:

  - `String[2]` *(array)*
  - `"String1"` *(String)*
  - `"String2"` *(String)*
- 4 variables<sup>1</sup>:

  - `args` *(method parameter)*
  - `args.length` *(instance variable)*
  - `args[0]` *(array component)*
  - `args[1]` *(array component)*

Note that if you create a `String[2]` and don't assign values to the array components (i.e. leave them `null`), you'd only have 1 object, but you'd still have 4 variables.

<sup>*1) Not counting private fields (instance variables) inside the `String` objects.*</sup>

---

`int a[2]={0};` is invalid code, and will fail to compile.

When using an initializer, you cannot specify the array size, since that is implicit in the initializer.

Also, you should always declared the `[]` array as part of the type, not as part of the name. Specifying the `[]` with the name is something inherited from the C language, and is high discouraged.

Correct declaration is:

```
int[] a = { 0 };
```

Which is:

- 1 object:

  - `int[1]` *(array)*
- 3 variables:

  - `a` *(local variable, kind #8)*
  - `a.length` *(instance variable)*
  - `a[0]` *(array component)*